# Want to change an image inside image view on button click

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to make a sort of database that stores characters from tv shows. Just for something to do.

I have 6 plain white imageviews on a user profile page under what would be their favourites. When a user clicks a button on the character page, a thumbnail of it's corresponding image should replace the first imageview.

If the first imageview has already been changed then move it into the 2nd and so on until you get to the 6th. At which point the user would get a message saying no more can be added.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit: What I have so far

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        empty.setImageResource(R.drawable.pikachuthumb);

        empty.remove(R.id.empty1);

        if(empty.getCount()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "No more favourites can be added. Please Refresh.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<ImageView> empty = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        empty.add(R.id.empty1);
        empty.add(R.id.empty2);
        empty.add(R.id.empty3);
        empty.add(R.id.empty4);
        empty.add(R.id.empty5);
        empty.add(R.id.empty6);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. Everybody can answer your question, but the thing is what Have you tried..?

Comment: Thanks! Well that's the thing. I'm a massive newbie so not really sure where to start. I'm assuming you could make an if statement in the onclick that would say something along the lines of

'if (empty()=!true){
imageview1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
}'

Not sure what the empty function would look like though.

Nor how to make it recognise if an image has already been filled by something else.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to have an `ArrayList` of all the `ImageView`s and call the `setImageResource()` method (or any other method to change the image), on the very first view(i.e. the view on `0th` index), on the click of the button. Next would be to remove the imageview from the list, once it has been changed. Keep repeating the process unless all imageviews are changed, then the arraylist would be empty, so show some toast message or friendly message about that.

Comment: Obviously this is throwing up errors but am I on the right lines? Still trying to work out how exactly to do what you said. Sorry for the trouble. See http://pastebin.com/FRZUZRJs